# Como faço para mostrar o quicksort aleatorizado passo a passo?

Tags: c, algoritmo, quicksort

Como faço para mostrar o processo de ordenação passo a passo? Seja mostrando o estado do vetor a cada troca ou mostrando uma árvore. Já tentei printar cada uma das três funções e também tentei criar uma função, mas os resultados só pioraram.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void swap(int A[], int i, int j){
    int temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}
int partition(int A[], int inicio, int fim) {
    int k;
    double d;
    d = (double) rand () / ((double) RAND_MAX + 1);
    k = d * (fim - inicio + 1);
    int randomIndex = inicio + k;
    swap(A, randomIndex, fim);
    //*******************ALGORITMO DE PARTIÇÃO DE CORMEN*********************
    //o pivo é o elemento final
    int pivo = A[fim];
    int i = inicio - 1;
    int j;
    /*
     * Este laço irá varrer os vetores da esquerda para direita
     * procurando os elementos que são menores ou iguais ao pivô.
     * Esses elementos são colocados na partição esquerda.
     */
    for (j = inicio; j <= fim - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] <= pivo){
            i = i + 1;
            swap(A, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(A, i + 1, fim);
    return i + 1; //retorna a posição do pivô
}
//Quicksort de Cormen
void quicksortAleatorizado(int A[], int inicio, int fim) {
    if (inicio < fim) {
        //realiza a partição
        int q = partition(A, inicio, fim);
        //ordena a partição esquerda
        quicksortAleatorizado(A, inicio, q - 1);
        //ordena a partição direita
        quicksortAleatorizado(A, q + 1, fim);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int vetor[] = {6, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 9, 10};
    int n = 10;
    quicksortAleatorizado(vetor, 0, n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um print dentro da função `swap` não seria suficiente?

Answer (score 0):

Ao contrario de linguagens de mais alto nível, como Python e JavaScript, que conseguem pegar qualquer tipo de dado e transforma-lo em algo legível para o usuário ao printar, em C a unica maneira de se mostrar os dados da maneira adequada é montando seu próprio algoritmo de exibição. Se você quiser mostrar os dados em forma de arvore, você terá que montar sua própria função para exibir a matriz do programa em em formato de árvore, isso vale pra qualquer formato que você deseja exibir os dados.